# Stop Mail from previewing pdfs and images in the body of an email

Tags: mail.app, email

Is there a way in the Mail.app to prevent it from previewing pdfs and images in the body of an email.

So that instead you just a get a normal file attachment ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the display of images (including PDF documents) can be disabled using this Terminal command:

```
defaults write com.apple.mail DisableInlineAttachmentViewing 1
```

The display of images/PDFs can be re-enabled by using this command:

```
defaults write com.apple.mail DisableInlineAttachmentViewing 0
```

Comment: Thanks, ill give that a shot, do you know, if wanted how to turn it back on ? - also is this available as a GUI 'preference' that could be toggled on and off ?

Comment: I've added additional information on how to re-enable the images. I do not know of a GUI option for this preference.

Comment: Note that now we must first give Terminal "Full Disk Access" in System Prefs. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/343356/70115 for more detail.