# How can I disable inline attachment previews (i.e. view as icon by default) in Mac Mail in macOS Mojave?

Tags: mail.app, email, preview, defaults

I would like to disable inline attachment previews by default, and instead view all attachments as icons in Mac's Mail app in macOS Mojave.

In High Sierra, the following terminal command *was* sufficient:

`defaults write com.apple.mail DisableInlineAttachmentViewing -bool yes`

**However this command does not work in Mojave.**

How can I accomplish this in Mojave?

Comment: You should clarify "does not work". Does the command fail with some kind of error message or does the command succeed but Mail still shows inline attachments?

Comment: In my case it does not produce an error but cannot change the behavior of Mail.

Answer (score 11):

Applications (including Terminal) do not get "full disk access" (e.g. your user files) any more in Mojave.

Try to grant Terminal access in...
`System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Full Disk Access`

Unlock the system preference panel, by clicking the lock at the bottom left and filling in your password.  Then either drag and drop Terminal.app onto the window, or navigate to it by clicking the plus sign (+).

[image: Full Disk Access]

Then launch Terminal and try your command again.

```
defaults write com.apple.mail DisableInlineAttachmentViewing -bool yes
```

PS. Alternatively you could disable SIP (System Integrity Protection) from Recovery, run your command, check that it worked and subsequently enable SIP again.  Less elegant, usually not advised (in case you forget to re-enable it again), a lot of booting in and out, but just as effective.

Comment: Just as clarification: After you ran the command you can remove Terminal from Full Disk Access again as well, just like re-enabling SIP in the other, less recommended way. :)

Comment: @Gero Yes, as soon as Terminal has been allowed to write to Mail's preference file, it can be deauthorized again until you need to do the same all over again for some other command. :)

Comment: This does not work for me. I added Terminal.app to Full Disk Access. The command goes through without an error message.

Comment: The format of the setting is changed `defaults write com.apple.mail DisableInlineAttachmentViewing -int 1` works on Catalina - Use -int 0 to disable

Comment: This works when you *compose* mail, but when you are viewing mail, this doesn't work. And there is nothing you can do about it in Mac Mail as of now (Dec 2020). Read more on this thread: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252108838