# Setting Safari preferences from script on Big Sur

Tags: safari, command-line, big-sur, defaults, apple-silicon

I have a Mac mini 2020 with an M1 processor and running macOS Big Sur.

On older macs I had this script to set Safari preferences

```sh
# Show status bar
defaults write com.apple.Safari ShowStatusBar -bool true
defaults write com.apple.Safari ShowOverlayStatusBar -bool true
# Show the full URL in the address bar (note: this still hides the scheme)
defaults write com.apple.Safari ShowFullURLInSmartSearchField -bool true
# Safari opens with: last session
defaults write com.apple.Safari AlwaysRestoreSessionAtLaunch -bool true
# Set Safari’s home page to `about:blank` for faster loading
defaults write com.apple.Safari HomePage -string "about:blank"
# Enable the Develop menu and the Web Inspector in Safari
defaults write com.apple.Safari IncludeDevelopMenu -bool true
# Enable Safari’s debug menu
defaults write com.apple.Safari IncludeInternalDebugMenu -bool true
# Update extensions automatically
defaults write com.apple.Safari InstallExtensionUpdatesAutomatically -bool true
# Make Safari’s search banners default to Contains instead of Starts With
defaults write com.apple.Safari FindOnPageMatchesWordStartsOnly -bool false
# Website use of location services
# 0 = Deny without prompting
# 1 = Prompt for each website once each day
# 2 = Prompt for each website one time only
defaults write com.apple.Safari SafariGeolocationPermissionPolicy -int 2
```

However, none of them seem to work anymore. Is there a new way to set similar preferences?

Comment: The subset of these that I use are working just fine, for me (new M1 MacBook Pro).  Can you clarify what you mean by not working?  Try `defaults read com.apple.Safari > a.txt`, then Safari > Settings > change something, then `defaults read com.apple.Safari > b.txt` and `diff a.txt b.txt` to see what's changing.  If Safari is open then `defaults write` changes might not show up right away.

Comment: For me the settings are completely ignored

Answer (score 2):

I had to enable Disk Access to terminal app (or in my case iTerm). Once access was granted all Safari settings were honored and persistent.

See this answer: [How can I disable inline attachment previews (i.e. view as icon by default) in Mac Mail in macOS Mojave?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/343343/how-can-i-disable-inline-attachment-previews-i-e-view-as-icon-by-default-in-m/343356#343356)

Comment: Thank you for sharing this!! This has been driving me mad!!  I was wondering why I couldn't read or write anything from terminal, but sure enough, this setting did the trick!  Once I granted access, I could read and write exactly as I needed.  So now, I have to make sure that is the absolute first thing I do before doing any scripting.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The one for "Show Status Bar" is

> defaults write com.apple.Safari ShowOverlayStatusBar -bool true

Found here along with others.
https://gist.github.com/alanzeino/42b6d983c7aa2f29d64ea2749621f7cf